# Printing words and PHP variable

Tags: php, variables, printing

I am trying to print a list of items, with the calculated of the quantity next to it. So far, only the quantity is printed next to the image. I need the value (i.e Apple) to appear as well. The value did appear, until I added 'quantity'.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
echo "<br/><br/><br/> You are leaving on ". $_POST["departuredate"]."</p>"; 
echo "You are returning on ". $_POST["returndate"]."</p>"; 

$return= strtotime($_POST["returndate"]);
$depart = strtotime($_POST["departuredate"]);
$datediff = $return - $depart;
echo "You are going for <b> ";
$quantity=floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
echo $quantity;
echo " days";


 $Yoghurt= 'Yoghurt' + $quantity;
 $Apple = 'Apple' + $quantity;
 $Banana = 'Banana' + $quantity;


....


$FoodList=array_unique($FoodList);
$img_path = 'empty_checkbox.gif';

if(!empty($FoodList))
{
   foreach ($FoodList as $key => $value)
   {
      echo "<li>" . "<img src='$img_path' />" . "    ". $value ."</li>";
   }
   echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: From where `$FoodList` comes?

Comment: `$Yoghurt= 'Yoghurt' + $quantity;` The `+` comes from JavaScript. It has to be a `.`

Answer (score 2):

Use `.` to concat variables to a string, not `+`. `+` is the mathematical addition operator. PHP typecasts the string to a `1` and adds it to `$quantity`.

```
$Yoghurt= 'Yoghurt' . $quantity;
$Apple = 'Apple' . $quantity;
$Banana = 'Banana' . $quantity;
```

See [string operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) for more in-depth information.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you don't use `+` to join (concatenate strings), you should use `.` instead.